# Change data of a sql table every 30 seconds

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am trying to test the refresh method of Windows Forms. We are using both windows forms and wpf in the project. Its a wpf window, popped out of windows form. I am calling the Initialize component of wpf again on windows forms refresh.

I need help on the sql side. Updating the data in database table periodically.
How to change the data of the SQL table which is bound to the grid? Database used is SQL Server CE.

Comment: Do you have any SQL Knowledge or do you expect ot magically learn somthing by asking instead of reading a tutorial?

Comment: I do but, I haven't done anything similar before. I would be glad if someone points me towards a relevant tutorial, not any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinForms the forms do not have an inherent way of storing data to a DB. You must add a `BindingSource` component to the form.

The `Refresh` method only updates the form visually but does not save any data. According to Microsoft:

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

Comment: I did that. I need help only on the sql side.

Comment: Your question did not mention any SQL.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.